# Flash Plugin for Firefox Quantum in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, flash, firefox-extensions

I have downloaded `tar.gz` file of the lastest firefox-quantum today.

I don't wish the old firefox to be replaced.
Like the old firefox, I didn't find any single plugin especially the flash-plugin npapi installed in the quantum.

What should I do to enable/install the flash plugin for Firefox-Quantum?

PS: There's no plugin folder in the extracted files of the ffx-quantum otherwise I would've just moved the `libflashplayer.so` to the plugins folder!

Comment: The installation procedure for *plug-ins* like Flash Player didn't change in Firefox Quantum. What changed is the removal of the interface for legacy *add-ons* which are not the same as *plug-ins*.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

Just create a folder named `plugins` within the `firefox/browser` directory (i.e. in the extracted `tar.gz` of the latest version)

Move `libflashplayer.so` into the plugins folder you created

Now start Firefox (latest) and it will detect the npapi flash plugin.

Worked for me in Ubuntu14.04.5

PS - outdated Firefox still remains, which is no problem... for the time being